# VBA: user-defined type not defined MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Tags: vba, excel

I am to prepare a demo for Reporting. For this we need to use VBA.
We have to display some data from Reporting tool using ODATA and update the data via web service.

[Blog to Consume ODATA using VBA](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcelolr/2010/02/16/consuming-odata-with-office-vba-part-i/)

I write the same code , But I am getting ***Compile error : user-defined type not defined***. I have added reference as defined in the blog , See the Image of the code and Reference below.

[image: Code with Error]

[image: Reference]

Can anybody guide how solve this ?

Thank and Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should the line be

```
Set objXmlHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
```

?

Failing that, looking in my registry, I see that 
MSXML2.XMLHTTP has CLSID {F6D90F16-9C73-11D3-B32E-00C04F990BB4}
and the InprocServer32 for this class is 
%SystemRoot%\System32\msxml3.dll

If the code mandates that you use MSXML2.XMLHTTP you could try adding 
%SystemRoot%\System32\msxml3.dll as a project reference (or the dll that hosts MSXML2.XMLHTTP on your PC)

Comment: Snap you beat me, (I've respectfully deleted my identical answer).

Comment: This works for me. The reference is Microsoft XML v6.0